# How do I change the font size to zoom in and out in Araxis Merge on MacOS?

Tags: macos, araxis, araxis-merge

I went through all the settings and the `Show Fonts` panel and could not find any solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up contacting support. This was their solution which I'm documenting for future searchers:

1. From Merge's main menu select: Araxis Merge > Preferences
2. Navigate to: File Comparisons > Fonts/Colours
3. For each of Unchanged, Inserted, Removed and Changed:
   Click the Change… button, change the font size and close the font panel
4. Click the OK button.

Comment: you are my hero!